# omp in mexfunction crashes Matlab

Tags: matlab, openmp, mex

I am trying to use omp to accelerate my mexfunction. However, it crashes Matlab every time. I am sorry for the long code. However, I don't know where comes the mistake, so I have to post all of them. The code works well without using omp.

```
#include <math.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "mex.h"
#include <omp.h>
using namespace std;


void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
/* Macros for the ouput and input arguments */
#define T1_OUT plhs[0]
#define T2_OUT plhs[1]
#define point_IN prhs[0]
#define PlaneLocation_IN prhs[1]
#define SearchRadius_IN prhs[2]
#define NeighborIndex_IN prhs[3]
#define D_IN prhs[4]
#define pi 3.14159265358979

double *point,*PL,R,*NI,*T1,*T2,*tempPr,*DP2P;
int i,j,k;
int NumOfPoints;
int NumOfNeighbors;
double vector2[3];
double vector1[3];
double cross[3];
double V;

vector<int> idIN;
vector<double> GPStime;
vector<double> LineInBallLength;


// define input pointers.
point = mxGetPr(point_IN);
PL = mxGetPr(PlaneLocation_IN);
R = mxGetScalar(SearchRadius_IN);
NI = mxGetPr(NeighborIndex_IN);
DP2P = mxGetPr(D_IN);

V = 4.0/3.0*pi*R*R*R; 


NumOfPoints = mxGetM(point_IN);
NumOfNeighbors = mxGetN(NeighborIndex_IN);

T1_OUT = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(NumOfPoints,1,mxREAL);
T2_OUT = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(NumOfPoints,1,mxREAL);
T1 = mxGetPr(T1_OUT);
T2 = mxGetPr(T2_OUT);

double Dist;
double Coef;
double Noise;

#pragma omp parallel 
{
    #pragma omp for //if I comment this line and the two lines above, the code works OK.
    for(i=0;i<NumOfPoints;i++){

    double pointX = point[i+ NumOfPoints];
    double pointY = point[i + NumOfPoints *2];
    double pointZ = point[i + NumOfPoints * 3];

    idIN.clear();
    GPStime.clear();
    for(j=0;j<NumOfPoints;j++){
        vector2[0] = pointX - point[j+ NumOfPoints];
        vector2[1] = pointY - point[j + NumOfPoints * 2];
        vector2[2] = pointZ - point[j + NumOfPoints * 3];
        vector1[0] = pointX - PL[j];
        vector1[1] = pointY - PL[j + NumOfPoints];
        vector1[2] = pointZ - PL[j + NumOfPoints * 2];
        cross[0] = vector2[1]*vector1[2] - vector2[2]*vector1[1];
        cross[1] = vector2[2]*vector1[0] - vector2[0]*vector1[2];
        cross[2] = vector2[0]*vector1[1] - vector2[1]*vector1[0];


        Dist =  sqrt(cross[0]*cross[0] + cross[1]*cross[1] + cross[2]*cross[2]) / DP2P[j];

        if (Dist <=R){
            idIN.push_back(j);
            GPStime.push_back(point[j]);
            LineInBallLength.push_back(2*sqrt(R*R - Dist*Dist));
        }
    }

    // Calculate Coef
    sort(GPStime.begin(),GPStime.end());
    GPStime.erase(unique(GPStime.begin(),GPStime.end()),GPStime.end());

    Coef = double(GPStime.size()) * 100 / double(idIN.size());

    Noise = 0;
    for(k=0;k<idIN.size();k++){
        Noise = Noise + LineInBallLength[k]*point[4*NumOfPoints+idIN[k]] / V * Coef;
    }
    T1[i] = Noise;

}
}
return;
}
```

Also I tried another short example using omp and it works. The computation time is about one fourth of the original time since my computer has four cores. Can anyone help me with this, thanks. 
By the way, I am very new in writing C code, so any other suggestions about the C code is appreciated.

Update:
I tried to revise the omp part as following

```
#pragma omp parallel for shared(point, DP2P, R, PL) private(pointX,pointY,pointZ,idIN,GPStime,vector1,vector2,cross,Dist, LineInBallLength,Noise)
```

Right now, matlab will not crash and can get a result. However, this result is not the same as the one without omp. For most of the result values, they are close to the right one (result without omp) and some of them are quite different from the right ones.

Comment: The code is riddled with race conditions. You should just read a good introduction to parallel programming with OpenMP. Unfortunately just throwing in a `pragma omp parallel for` is not enough.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you provide some more details or is there a good introduction you recommend. I am new to this field so I am not sure if I can find the right thing.

Comment: I read something about race conditions. My guess is that maybe I need to use reduction to protect the result. The result I need is a mxArray, T1. Is it possible to put that in reduction? And if so, how should I do this. Thanks.

Comment: First, you should be very proficient in C (or C++ or Fortran). Here is a [good book list for that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/562377/620382). The official OpenMP site lists [books](http://www.openmp.org/resources/openmp-books/) and [tutorials](http://www.openmp.org/resources/tutorials-articles/).

Comment: @Zulan,Thank you very much.